# Why does this code always produces a "Internal System Error: 1731640370-112053 (-1981348559)"?

Tags: apex, map, errormessages, error

To add Ids to a Set without looping over a list of SObjects I tried to do the following.
In every org I tried it leads to this error:

```
Set<Opportunity> myset = new Set<Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
Map<Id, Opportunity> mymap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(mySet);
System.debug(mymap.keySet());
```

when I try to save. When I just change

```
Set<Opportunity> myset = new Set<Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
Map<Id, Opportunity> mymap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(new List<Opportunity>(mySet));
System.debug(mymap.keySet());
```

it works. Why?!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? Why do you create an Opportunity Set, and then creating a Map from that? Why don't you directly do `Map<Id, Opportunity> mymap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);`

Comment: This is a stripped down version of my code. In the actual class there is just a set and not SOQL. Anyway this should generally work and my question is not so much "does this code fragment" make sense but "why does it fail so miserably?" ;)

Comment: There's probably a "here be dragons" label on the Apex compiler. I can't find it now but there was a crazy question about thing similar to `Map<Decimal, List<Set<Map<Id, Integer.class>>>>` and it was compiling ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_from_SObjects.htm

`Map<Id, sObject>` can be initialized with a `List<sObject>` or a `[query]`.

Or - without the `()` - with `{comma, separated, list, of, items, in, curly braces}`.

There's no method to initialize it with a set. Similarly [`putAll`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) method accepts a compatible map or a list, but not a set. Why did you think you can use a set?

Just Use PJC's suggested code :)

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> mymap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
Set<Id> mySet = mymap.keyset();
```